# Why get method not work in Laravel and AngularJS project

Tags: angularjs, laravel

I want to develop simple front end AngularJS and backend Laravel. I don't know why my AngularJS route is not connected with laravel route.It keep mention as `GET http://localhost/todos 404 (Not Found)`. I hope someone can help me to solve it. Thanks in advance.

Hello.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Laravel + Angularjs</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-App>
    <div id="todos" ng-controller="Todoctrl">
    <h3 class="page-header">Todos<small ng-if="remaining()">{{remaining()}} remaining</small>
    </h3>
    <ul  class="unstyled">
        <li ng-repeat="todo in todos">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="todo.done">
            {{todo.text}}
        </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</script>
    <script src="js/app.js">
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Todo.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Todo extends Model
{
    protected $guarderd = [];

}
```

App.js

```
function Todoctrl($scope,$http){
    $http.get("/todos").success(function(todos){
        $scope.todos = todos;
    });
    $scope.remaining = function(){
        var count = 0;
        angular.forEach($scope.todos,function(todo){
            count == todo.done ? 0 : 1;
        });

    }
}
```

Route.php

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
Route::get('/',function(){
    return view('hello');
});
Route::get('/todos',function(){
    return Todo::all();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the whole URI like `http://locahost:8000/todos` and if you get problems with CORS you can use this library: [LARAVEL CORS](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors)

NOTE: You must try this command too `php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0`